# Manual content negotiation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Is it possible to access the methods that ASP.NET Core uses to negotiate content?

For example, I would expect a method that does:

```
var acceptHeader = "text/*, text/html, text/html;level=1, */*";
var candidates = new[] { "image/png", "text/plain" };
var preferred = Negotiate(candidates, acceptHeader) // returns text/plain.
```

I found [a library](https://github.com/danislu/httpheaderparser) that does it. As ASP.NET Core is doing content negotiation behind the scenes I would prefer to use .NET Core methods to avoid adding a new library to the project.

Comment: 1. ASP.NET Core parses the `Accept: ` header by using an [**internal** helper class](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/AcceptHeaderParser.cs#L20) This class is internal and there's no public wrapper service around it. Obviously, Microsoft doesn't want to expose this functions to developers. 2. Could you please tell us why you need this information? If you need return different content according to the `Accept: `header, it's better to create a custom OutputFormatter instead of parse the desired content type?

Comment: 1. What is the name of the internal class? 2. I need to reply in “exotic” formats such as pdf, png, jpg, depending on the Accept header.

Comment: 1. It's `AcceptHeaderParser`. See [src here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/AcceptHeaderParser.cs#L10) 2. Maybe you need a [OutputFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#specify-valid-media-types-and-encodings) ?

Answer (score -1):

You  can build your own middleware component to achieve this goal.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{

  Negotiate(context);
  await _next(context);
}
```

And don't forget to register your middleware

```
services.AddScoped<IMiddleware, SomeMiddleware>();
```